# Программа возвращает код символа а не сам символ

Tags: java

Всем привет! 
Метод sumDigitsInNumber должен возвращать сумму цифр полученного числа (546), но вместо этого возвращает сумму кодов чисел из таблицы ASCII(возвращает 159, сумма кодов 53 + 52 + 54), изучаю Java меньше недели и никак не могу понять в чем проблема, пытался гуглить, но ничего не нагуглил. Помогите пожалуйста)

P.S. столкнулся с проблемой не только в этой программе, для себя написал программу "угадай число" и там при вводе числа с клавиатуры через BufferedReader тоже возвращался код символа(

Заранее всем спасибо!)

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumDigitsInNumber(546));
    }

    public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {
        String s = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            number += (int) chars[i];
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делал буквально на днях, но двумя другими способами. Здесь используются мои имена пакетов.

Основной класс SumOfDigits.java:

```
package info.sjd;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import info.sjd.service.SumOfDigitsService;

public class SumOfDigits {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SumOfDigits.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 12345;

        int sumOfDigitsByIntegerDivision = SumOfDigitsService.sumOfDigitsByIntegerDivision(number);
        int sumOfDigitsByCharSplitting = SumOfDigitsService.sumOfDigitsByCharSplitting(number);

        logger.info("The sum of digits of number " + number + " by integer division is " + sumOfDigitsByIntegerDivision);
        logger.info("The sum of digits of number " + number + " by character splitting is " + sumOfDigitsByCharSplitting);
    }
}
```

Сервисный класс SumOfDigitsService.java:

```
package info.sjd.service;

public class SumOfDigitsService {
    public static int sumOfDigitsByIntegerDivision(int number) {
        int sumOfDigits = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            sumOfDigits = sumOfDigits + (number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return sumOfDigits;
    }

    public static int sumOfDigitsByCharSplitting(int number) {
        int sumOfDigits = 0;
        String stringNumber = String.valueOf(number);
        for (int i = 0; i < String.valueOf(number).length(); i++) {
            sumOfDigits = sumOfDigits + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(stringNumber.charAt(i)));

        }

        return sumOfDigits;
    }
}
```

В вашем случае скорее всего нужно будет разобраться с приведением типов и возможно использовать переопределение метода .toString()...

========== ОБНОВЛЕНО =================

Да, с приведением типов разберитесь. Все работает, если так: 
    package info.sjd;

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumDigitsInNumber(546));
    }

    public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {
        String s = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            number += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(chars[i]));
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, с приведением типов разберитесь. Все работает, если так: package info.sjd;

    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(sumDigitsInNumber(546));
        }

        public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {
            String s = Integer.toString(number);
            char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
            number = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                number += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(chars[i]));
            }
            return number;
        }
    }

Comment: Спасибо)

Но все таки, если не сложно, можете объяснить почему в моем варианте возвращает код ASCII а не символ?

Comment: Я и сам в Java новичок, просто занимаюсь ей дольше вас. Поэтому доходчиво объяснить не смогу. Приходилось решать много задач на тех же https://www.codewars.com например. По поводу преобразования char в int  просто и доходчиво написано здесь - https://www.javatpoint.com/java-char-to-int . А вообще, что касается преобразования типов в Java -  это все надо пережить, пропустить через себя на множестве задач. Тогда интуитивно будете чувствовать.

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Answer (score 1):

Каст `char` в `int` возвращает код символа, а не его цифровое значение. Это задокументированное поведение. Для получения численного значения можно использовать `Character.getNumericValue(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

Адаптация алгоритма из вопроса:

```
public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    for (char c : Integer.toString(number).toCharArray()) {
        sum += Character.getNumericValue(c);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

Другой подход:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumDigitsInNumber(546));  // 15
    }

    public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {
        int sum = 0;

        while (number > 0) {
            sum += number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Объяснение:

- `number % 10` - возвращает последную цифру числа: для 546 - 6, для 15 - 5.
- `number /= 10` - уменьшает число на 1 цифру: 546 -> 54, 15 -> 1

---

Можно использовать `Stream` из java8:

```
public static int sumDigitsInNumber(int number) {
    return Arrays
        .stream(Integer.toString(number).split("")) // Конвертирование в массив String
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)                // Конвертирование каждой строки в число
        .sum();                                     // Подсчет суммы
}
```